# Making content type fields into an exposed filter dropdown?

Tags: 8

I have several taxonomy reference fields in a content type that I would like to make into an exposed filter dropdown. With other taxonomy reference fields, it's easier to do so because they only have one parent term for each vocabulary. In this particular case, though, I have a vocabulary term with parent and child terms.

Since the contextual filter isn't working for me in this case, I was wondering if there were maybe any modules out there that can combine all of the content fields that I want and create an exposed filter dropdown with them.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you wanting to create a Drupal View's exposed filter with terms from multiple vocabularies? Or do you want to create an exposed filter from only one vocabulary, but with many terms (some parents, some children)? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If creating a views exposed filter:

1. Go to the "Filters" section and add a filter.
2. For the filter: Select your node field (where you reference taxonomy terms)
3. For the filter config: select "Select List" and the vocabularies you want listed in the exposed filter.
4. For the filter options: select "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"